# How Google Play Services recognizes driving?

Tags: android, android-activity, geofencing

I am very interested to know how Google Play Services recognize your driving state.
From what I know even if I disable all location providers and stop location tracking the activity recognition service still able to recognize that I am in driving state.

I am using Nexus 3 and from what I understand from Jelly Bean version and only on devices that support it, Google is using something that is called Hardware Geofencing. Can someone point me to the right direction or explain me how they do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services has some things you can use.

See `ActivityRecognitionResult`, `DetectedActivity` and `ActivityRecognitionClient`

Uses permission: `com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION`

There is a broadcast receiver that monitors your activities. Whenever you check the receiver for the current state:

```
//Returns enum value, one of: IN_VEHICLE, ON_BICYCLE, ON_FOOT, STILL, UNKNOWN... 
DetectedActivity activity = activityRecognitionResult.getMostProbableActivity();

//Returns the confidence level that the activity.getType() is accurate
int confidence = activity.getConfidence();

//TODO -- Determine if the confidence meets or exceeds a threshold for taking action
```

**Update**

See Google's documentation here for a high-level explanation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient.html:

`The activities are detected by periodically waking up the device and reading short bursts of sensor data. It only makes use of low power sensors in order to keep the power usage to a minimum.`

Just guessing here, but I'm guessing there is an algorithm for profiling each type of activity. For example, the motion of a phone in your pocket is while walking (low frequency, high impact) is much different than when you are riding a bicycle (high frequency, low impact, variations in altitude).

If the algorithms factor in GPS speed, then certainly you aren't walking at 80 mph. If you are driving, you may have very little 'shake'/gyroscopic movement of the phone, but there might be a high G-force indicated (accelerometer).

I am guessing that these algorithms are not open-source, as they would seem to give Google a nice competitive advantage.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was do you know what are the algorithms behind their activity recognition (specifically driving) and not how to use Google Play Services.

Comment: I suspect akodiakson added this in his update after your comment - but "these algorithms are not open-source" is correct. Everything that uses Google Play Services is part of the "Google Experience" and not part of the open source Android code.